# How to check that native notifications are enabled for chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I can block notification in chrome by set ['off' in notification settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oiDq.png).
And after that when I send notification with `chrome.notifications.create` I didn't receive any error.

I tried to check permission with `chrome.notifications.getPermissionLevel` and got 'granted'.
I tried to check that no one notification is appeared with `chrome.notifications.getAll`, but suddenly they were added, but didn't show.

There is a way to check that I can show a notification to the user?

Comment: No, there's no API for extensions and maybe Chrome itself can't even see this setting in OS.